# Whenever Cron With Multiple Projects On Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, whenever, whenever-capistrano

I use whenever in my rails apps and deploy it with capistrano.

The trouble is that since I use it only for one project there's no problem, but when I use whenever for more projects on the same server, everytime I deploy my project I destroy and recreate the cron file. I need that every project update it or append new instruction, to coexists on the same server.

I simply deploy with

deploy.rb

```
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "whenever/capistrano"
...
after "deploy:create_symlink", "deploy:update_crontab"
....
```

Someone can teach me how can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to namespace your projects or they'll overwrite each other when you deploy:

```
set :whenever_environment, defer { stage }
set :whenever_identifier, defer { "#{application}_#{stage}" }
require "whenever/capistrano"
```

Comment: great I will test it soon :)

Answer (score 0):

With capistrano V3, in your deploy file:

```
set :whenever_identifier, ->{ "#{fetch(:application)}_namespace" }
```